# C# Update MySql after edited DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a problem to save my data into `MySql` database from `DataGridView`.

When i insert a new value into `Cell` of selected row of `DataGridView` and press the button `buttonSalvaContatore` the data won't save on the database.

What's wrong?

This is when i fill `DataGridView`

```
const string queryRicerca = "SELECT * FROM colori ORDER BY id_colore ASC";
using (daColori = db.ExecuteDataAdapter(queryRicerca))
{

    mySqlCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daColori);
    daColori.UpdateCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    daColori.InsertCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

    daColori.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dsColori = new DataSet();t
    daColori.Fill(dsColori, "colori"); 
    bSource.DataSource = dsColori.Tables["colori"];
    dataGridColori.DataSource = bSource;
    dataGridColori.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Codice";
    ((DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridColori.Columns[0]).MaxInputLength = 2;
    dataGridColori.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    dataGridColori.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Descrizione";
    dataGridColori.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

And this is my button

```
private void buttonSalvaColore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridColori.CurrentRow != null)
    {

        dataGridColori.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = textBoxCodiceColore.Text;
        dataGridColori.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = textBoxDescColore.Text;

        daColori.Update(dsColori,"colori");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update all pending changes of your`BindingSource` by calling `EndEdit` after you update the`DataGridView`.

```
dataGridColori.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = textBoxCodiceColore.Text;
dataGridColori.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = textBoxDescColore.Text;
bSource.EndEdit();
daColori.Update(dsColori,"colori");
```

For reference: [BindingSource.EndEdit() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx)